# what is wrong with pandas date_time?

Tags: pandas, datetime

Following is the code for an example of using `pandas datetime` module. As shown in the output, it is not consitent, It is mixing `date` and `month`. Am i doing something wrong? 
​

```
dates = ['20/11/17', '12/02/18', '02/05/18', '10/09/18', 
         '22/06/17', '12/02/15','19/11/17', '04/09/16', 
         '12/05/18', '11/04/15', '10/04/17', '13/06/16']
data = pd.DataFrame(data=dates, columns=['date'])
data['date_format'] = pd.to_datetime(dates)
data
```

Output:

```
      date      date_format
0   20/11/17    2017-11-20
1   12/02/18    2018-12-02
2   02/05/18    2018-02-05
3   10/09/18    2018-10-09
4   22/06/17    2017-06-22
5   12/02/15    2015-12-02
6   19/11/17    2017-11-19
7   04/09/16    2016-04-09
8   12/05/18    2018-12-05
9   11/04/15    2015-11-04
10  10/04/17    2017-10-04
11  13/06/16    2016-06-13
```

Comment: nothing is wrong with it . . . it is working as it should just specify `dayfirst`: `data['date_format'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'], dayfirst=True)`

Comment: Thanks @Chris, you just saved my day.